# PHP token security

Tags: php, security, authentication, token

I wrote a PHP application which requires a login. This application is private so no new users can register. First I used sessions to identify the users but it lead to problems on tablets because they lost their sessions. I think this is because of energy saving operations.

Now I changed my application to generate a random security token. So the authentication is as the follows:

- Log in
- Generate random security token and save it to disk
- Redirect the browser to http://myhost/site?id=[securitytoken]
- On the server side I check if the file exists - if yes, user is authenticated

Everything is now working perfectly I am just thinking about security concerns. It is no problem if the user sees the security token. Is it somehow possible to find out the token when I use GET? I am using SSL.

I tried to change the expiration times and cookie lifetimes. On a normal computer it is working as it should. On the table it is also working **IF** it does not go into standby (meaning the screen gets black). If the screen gets black, the session expires very soon.

Comment: You have basically re-invented sessions.  Why not just use what's built-in and change the expiration time?

Comment: energy saving has nothing to do with sessions. a standard php session puts its id into a cookie. if you're losing a session on a client, then either the client deleted (or expired) the session cookie, or you have a cookie settings error and the client isn't sending back the cookie as it should be.

Comment: I tried to change the expiration times and cookie lifetimes. On a normal computer it is working as it should. On the table it is also working IF it not goes into standby (meaning the screen gets black). If the screen gets black, the session expires very soon.

Comment: probably because those without wires are deleting what could be for them, temporary files as goes all the previous data in cache. check to see the time for the cookie life and anything in your server's settings that itself could be causing.

Comment: search for "session fixation", that might be an issue with your approach.  If your security token is effectively an SID, (session id) then it has it's drawbacks.  Like if I can check your browser history I'll see it, or if someone prints a page and the url gets printed at the top of the page.  Minor issues but I think the ones that get you usually are.

Comment: *Hm....*, thinking outloud; save the security token to disk, store a longtime and temporary cookie related to it, once the token's been used a second time, delete it from disk and use a fresh one later. Again, just *thinking outloud*.

Comment: @ThomasSparber - Why worry when the computers are working as expected? hackers and criminals reply on that mindset.

Comment: Hmmm this can lead to a security flaw, if I know the token value I can literally take over of the session as if I were logged in the system. With a simple sniffer this attack can be achieved.

Comment: @RamyDeeb they're on SSL. How could that be sniffed?

Comment: If you can't use cookies to store the PHPSID, try `window.localStorage` in Javascript. In combination with clientside public key authentication (`travist/jsencrypt`) it should be very *bulletproof*.

Comment: @RamyDeeb See this article on  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19616/why-is-it-possible-to-sniff-an-https-ssl-request - However, this article *makes me shudder a bit* http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/

Comment: @DanFromGermany This sounds very good, i will take a look thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's all about **trust**. MITM is impossible without the private key and when the client validates against a (trusted) public key. For *normal* people, MITM with unencrypted / http traffic is difficult (only W-LAN, which is rather easy to crack). MITM with encrypted / https traffic, is very very difficult, almost impossible for *normal* people. MITM requires spoofing of ARP table, WLAN access, or access to any device between client and internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vulnerability inherent to using GET instead of, for example, POST from a network perspective.

The only caveat you should keep in mind is that a GET request is more likely to be stored on the client (e.g. browser history) in a way you might not intend. For these reasons, I typically use POST requests for authentication.

The problem you are attempting to solve sounds remarkably similar to ["remember me" cookies](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2). The linked blog post might be helpful in mitigating the security risks involved in designing token-base authentication systems.

Generally, web apps are confined to using `localStorage` and cannot silently read/write to files in the background. How are you accomplishing this?

When you say you're using SSL, do you really mean TLS or do you mean SSL version 3? If SSLv3, I would advise updating your stack and webserver configuration to support [current best standards](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS). TLSv1.2 with ECDHE and AES-GCM + SHA2 or ChaCha20-Poly1305 are ideal.

Comment: Very nice and comprehensive answer, thanks! Yes, I'm using TLS but thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

GET is more vulnerable than POST as it can be transmitted and stored:

- In server logs by default.
- In corporate proxy logs.
- In the `referer` header if your page uses external resources or links to external domains.

In your example you have a `http` URL (this could be a typo though as you said you are using SSL). Make sure you are using `https` URLs to protect this data in transit.

This approach could also be vulnerable to [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) as an attacker could get the user to visit a URL containing, or redirecting to, the same session ID as the attacker. When the victim logs in, the shared session will be authenticated meaning the attacker is now also logged in. To protect against this, refresh the session ID upon login and logout.

Cookies are often the preferred approach for session handling as they are harder to attack in the above scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with in URL variables in the get form means that for one : users can easily modify it (by accident or not) and they stay even when the link is copied somewhere.

If you send someone your link/someone gets your link with the id variable in it,is that a security risk to you?

Comment: An intercepting proxy can also be used to MitM an app and arbitrarily change any HTTP request (including POST requests).

Comment: If the users modify the link then the session "expires" and they need to re-login. Then it's their fault :-) This is fine for me. Sending the link incl. security token is also no problem for me. thanks

Comment: Scott everything is possible,but some are more obvious than others!